# How to use attribute autocomplete in chips in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a chips tag in primefaces and it has attribute autocomplete but I dont know how to use it as suggestion.
See my code below

```
<p:chips id="chips" value="#{partner.listString}" autocomplete="how to use auto complete here">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="itemList"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" update="itemList"/>
</p:chips>
```

This is my expectation. But I dont know how to do it?
[image]

[link showcase]https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/chips.xhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for the autocomplete component with multiple=true: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Comment: This is great. It doesn't seem to allow user-defined values though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSF 2.2 you can use [JSF Passthrough](https://www.primefaces.org/jsf-2-2-pass-through-attributes/) attributes.

First declare the namespace pt at the top of your XHTML document.

```
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

Then in your chips add pt: to the attribute.

```
<p:chips id="chips" pt:autocomplete="how to use auto complete here">
```

Comment: But how do you use it then?

Comment: I applied it pt:autocomplete="on" or any value it didn't work like in html attr.
I inspected element and I saw that it always autocomplete="off". I can also say autocomplete in chips is useless(correct me if i'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

The `autocomplete` attribute you are referring to is a property of [javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.html). From [Mozilla Developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete):

> The source of the suggested values is generally up to the browser; typically values come from past values entered by the user, but they may also come from pre-configured values. For instance, a browser might let the user save their name, address, phone number, and email addresses for autocomplete purposes. Perhaps the browser offers the ability to save encrypted credit card information, for autocompletion following an authentication procedure.

But I don't think it is actually used in Chips component, but @melloware gave you the workaround using passthrough attributes.

Basically, Chips is a free words picker where you get all your words typed represented as a list (after conversion/validation). While, Autocomplete component is based on a preset list defined by the developer. Depending on what you want to do, @melloware and @tandraschko gave you the proper answers ;)